# Focus ring on NSPopupButton doesn't appear on pressing tab

Tags: cocoa, focus, osx-lion, nspopupbutton, tab-ordering

I have a couple of `NSPopupButtons` on my view and they are defined as a `newKeyView` after one of the text fields. The problem is that somehow they are not getting the focus ring when pressing the tab button comes to them, like they are ignored. What should be done in order for them to get a focus ring?

Thanks,

Nava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior in OSX is to only have certain controls be navigable by the tab key.  You can change this in the keyboard preferences pane in System Preferences.  In the Keyboard Shortcuts tab, select the "All controls" radio button.

Comment: that's interesting... now how to explain that to user?

Comment: Is it possible to show the focus ring on NSPopupButton without changing preferences?

Comment: I'm guessing that you can manually draw one, but that doesn't mean it can be tabbed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of NSPopupButton and override method canBecomeKeyView, returning YES. My code using python:

```
class ComboBox(AppKit.NSPopUpButton):
    def canBecomeKeyView(self):
        return True
```